# I want to create a chat application in Android so how do I create my own XMPP server, and how do I configure it?

Tags: android

I want to create a chat application in Android. So please tell me how to create my own XMPP server and how to configure it. Any type of PHP code is required or not. Please give me some suggestion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following chat application code:

http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample